# How can I make a background image reflect its direction?

Tags: java, android

if you allow me the picture below the question i put it background to the application screen
When the language of the application changes between Arabic and English the screen is reversed from left to right,in file (manifest) i do it this (android:supportsRtl="false") but the picture remains the same
But what happened is that the screen stops reversing when the language changes but I do not want this to happen. I want the screen to remain reflected when the language changes.and The image also reflects its direction as in the picture the second
Is there any instruction that can be added to reflect the image direction and change to the second picture ??

I have this instruction but I could not execute it on (ScrollView) because the picture set by the background of (Scrollview)

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.android_cookie_image_view );
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ4px.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le2GG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Get a refrence of the ScrollView and use this to set the background image:

```
scrollViewObject.setBackgroundResource(<the id of your image>);
```